# how to trigger a download dialog box instead of automatically playing video/viewing image

Tags: javascript

I wish to have a user click on a link to a video file and then have a dialog box open for them to save to file. I don't wish for the browser to open quicktime or any other plugin to process the video. how can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with JavaScript alone. Your server should set `Content-Disposition` header to `attachment`. For example in php you do something like `header("Content-Disposition:attachment;");`